# How to make api pagination with php?

Tags: php, api, function, pagination, json

There is a code api url and it is output json format.

API Link :`http://api.site.com/deal/browse.html?apiKey=VN43U6&itemInPage=100&p=100`

I want to explain api url value

> itemInPage=100 : Number of deal will be shown on the screen
>    p=100          : 100th Page

So I decode it and i call Title value

My Code:

```
 <?php
                $pagenum     = 20;
                $dealnum     = 100;
                $jsonurl     = 'http://api.site.com/deal/browse.html?apiKey=VN43U6&p=' . $pagenum . '&itemInPage=' . $dealnum;
                $json        = file_get_contents($jsonurl, 0, null, null);
                $json_output = json_decode($json);

                foreach ($json_output->deals as $objects) {
                                $title = $objects->title;

                                echo '<h5 class="coupon-title">' . $title . '</h5>';

                }
?>
```

My Code calling just 100 deal title in 20th page. I want to do this, call 20 page and 100 deal title per page as a result 2000 deal title and after i want to paginate it.

How can i make it?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you grab a json dump, decode it, and then want to paginate the key/value series by a range of 100 each time?
How about:

1) Create a basic html file with a head and empty div

2) make a asynchronous request to the decoded array (the request is directed your php file) for a lim of `current_index + 100`

3) Encode back into what format you need and then render with js; injecting the content into the div

Tell me what you think

Comment: Yes i want to do that but how i can do it? i don't know..I need help or sample code. Thanx for asnver @CristianCavalli

Comment: it looks like you might be able to iterate off of the url (p=100) I can't tell though because the site doesn't actually resolve. Anyway you might want to think about creating a hidden field with the page index and then on a page_advance() (or whatever to your pagination advance function is) create an asynchronous call to the url to fetch the hidden fields index+100. You'll have to create some mock-up code yourself, then feel free to post it if you need help. Check this out for some help: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp That's for a db but you could easily apply it to a file.

Comment: I'm not using db. I want to explain what i need, my code just calling 100 title like this itemInPage=100.. 100 is max. number of the page.. if i write 101 it will create still 100 title.. we have 1000 page and every page have 100 title so i want to paginate...I think i need fetch all page and after paginate it but how i can make  it i don't know. Any idea?